# 4 processors fail in ProLiant DL580 after swap

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, boot, shipping

I recently shipped my HP ProLiant DL580 G5, and am now in the process of trying to get it set up again. However, upon getting the power supplies and HDDs reinstalled, I was unable to power the thing on. I checked the system error panel, and it registered an internal error with processor #1. Figuring that it was possible that some connection in the socket had loosened during shipping, and that even if that weren't the case I could run the system with only 3 processors for a little while, I went ahead and swapped processors 1 and 4, since although processor 1 is critical for operation, processor 4 is partially redundant. However, upon trying to start the system up, I now get a new error- The power supplies and system fans spin up and it looks like the boot process begins (which was not happening before), but about 30 seconds in, the internal error light goes on again, but now registering errors on ALL 4 processors. What on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the ILO 2 web interface to read the server's IML log.

That will give you the exact reasoning for the system halting.

---

Edit:

There's a method to troubleshooting hardware. You need to get the reason for the errors.

- Break the system down to its bare minimum.
- Minimum RAM and one physical CPU.
- Try and boot.
- Record the messages or errors
- Add additional RAM and CPU.
- Repeat.

Work from there.

Comment: Unfortunately, ILO 2 is not configured for the server's current network. Is there any way to get at ILO when DHCP is disabled and the present network does not statically route to ILO?

Comment: Hit `F8` on the screen when prompted during the POST process. That will allow you to [configure the ILO networking and password](https://adyamarathon.files.wordpress.com/2007/09/ilo-user-management.jpg).

Comment: Unfortunately, the system does not appear to get far enough into POST to actually output anything to the screen. Is there something I could infer from the numbers on the motherboard LCD display? I haven't found any manual explaining those.

Comment: Take a laptop, configure it with an IP that the ILO has... Or connect the ILO and a computer to a DHCP-enabled network.

Comment: I was able to get into the ILO web interface, and the most recent entry is just complaining about a low charge on the Array Accelerator battery. According to ILO, the internal health LED is Ok, but my eyes say that it's flashing between green and red. I suppose that means breaking the system up.

Comment: All right, I don't understand how, or why that worked, but it did. I just loaded each processor sequentially, restarted between processors, and by the end, had all 4 in place again. Amazing.

Comment: It's magic!! :)